# jQuery Animate(ScrollLeft) ignores time parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

OK guys I can't wrap my head arround it:

```
thumb.animate(
  {'scrollLeft': active.width()*3},
  'slow'
);
```

It scrolls as it's supposed to, but the `"slow"` is completely ignored, meaning it scrolls in an instant and not slowly.

I hope you can help me with that... oh and yes `active.width()` is a number, since hence it wouldn't slide and throw errors with it wasn't

Comment: Is your element hidden ? You should play with positions values (i.e left) to animate it instead of scrollLeft.

Comment: nope, it's not. it's part of a slideshow, so the next image is just hidden by the `overflow:hidden` on the parent

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwYL/). You'll need to provide more info, and perhaps create a jsFiddle replicating the problem so we can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @soyuka you should animate it with `left` instead of `scrollLeft` as your images are hidden via `overflow:hidden` and images should be either absolutely or relatively positioned.

#### html:

```
<p class='thumb'>Hello</p>
```

#### css:

```
p { 
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
  border:2px solid #666; 
  width:250px; 
  position:relative;  //<----required it could also be absolute
}
```

#### jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
   $(".thumb").animate({left : 200},'slow');
});
```

#### [Output Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/exuyis/1/edit) check it out and see if this helps.

Comment: unfortunatly thumb is a div container whom scrollbar needs to be moved

Comment: @Soundz Okay!!!!! Then your code looks to be allright then, may be `active.width()*3` is not in the context it seems. If you could post a bit more code then it would be much more easier to debug it.

Comment: yeah i guess so, but it's rather hard to show. Would you mind it if I pm you the website, so you can have a look at it yourself?